# Best way to live database search in Inertia/Vue with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, inertiajs

I want to search the customers list and change the component as is.

At the moment I use this link to search for a specific customer /customer/$searchColumn/$searchTerm?page=4

This is what my controller returns

```
return Inertia::render('Dashboard', [
    'customers' => Customer::whereLike("nr", (string)$request)->paginate(10),
]);
```

A table with all found items paginated gets rendered.

Vue is very simple at the moment:

```
<script setup>
  import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
  import Pagination from '@/mycompany/Pagination.vue';
  const page = usePage()
</script>
```

And in front-end I render a table with:

```
v-for="customer in $page.props.customers.data"
```

I want a searchfield on top of the table, that reloads the results while I type.

I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

for this kind of thing, you can just use regular ajax/fetch request to do it.

Inertia still utilize laravel for routing, so it's kind of impossible to do that kind of form request without some kind of request or redirection.

Even `inertia.js` creator also support using [xhr/fetch request with inertia](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/issues/170#issuecomment-713880653).